# Distinct in a wm_concat in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, concat-ws

I made a query that get all rooms with its name, its address, and other data.

```
(select replace(wm_concat( '\par \tab ' || s.address|| '\par \tab ' || s.lib || '\par \tab '), ',', '\par - ')
 from t_room s)
```

Too long for all the data, the only one important data are the name and the address.

The fact is, 2 rooms can have the same address, so in result I don't want :

`room1 address1 - room2 address1`

that, I actually get, but

`room1 address1 - room2 at the same address`

is this possible in oracle 10?

I tried adding a distinct for the address field, but of course not possible.

Thank you.

Comment: So, whenever a room has the same address as the room before it, you want to get the `at the same address` string instead of the actual address?

Comment: @PrzemyslawKruglej Yes, because here, I just have `address` as value, but this can be a very long address, so instead of writing two times this long address, I got the `at the same address`instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that using `LAG` function:

```
CREATE TABLE t_room_s (
  room VARCHAR2(20),
  address VARCHAR2(20)
);

INSERT INTO t_room_s VALUES ('room1', 'addr 1');
INSERT INTO t_room_s VALUES ('room2', 'addr 1');
INSERT INTO t_room_s VALUES ('room3', 'addr 2');
INSERT INTO t_room_s VALUES ('room4', 'addr 3');
INSERT INTO t_room_s VALUES ('room5', 'addr 4');
INSERT INTO t_room_s VALUES ('room6', 'addr 4');
INSERT INTO t_room_s VALUES ('room7', 'addr 4');
INSERT INTO t_room_s VALUES ('room8', 'addr 5');

SELECT wm_concat(room || ' ' || addr) AS val
  FROM (
    SELECT
        room,
        CASE
          WHEN LAG(address, 1, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY address) = address THEN 'same address'
          ELSE address
        END AS addr
      FROM
        t_room_s
    ORDER BY address
  )
;
```

Output:

```
VAL
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
room1 addr 1,room2 same address,room3 addr 2,room4 addr 3,room5 addr 4,room6 same address,room7 same address,room8 addr 5
```

Comment: Thank you. There is so much oracle keywords I don't know.